# form tag is broken after calling custom form with AJAX

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, webforms

my custom form is working well. but when i want to call my custom form (in a custom mudule) via AJAX, the form tag is somehow not finished or broken.

```
<form class="myform" data-drupal-selector="myform" action="form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvYSKCf43t8qZYSwcfZl2uzM" method="post" id="myform" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

instead of the form tag with all elements (`data-drupal-form-fields="....."`) and `action="/mypage"`
they are all missing.

do i miss something when i build my form or is it just an issue with the core form api?

EDIT:

i found the part why its broke:

```
    class FormController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function createForm()
    {
        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(\Drupal\is_form\Form\MyForm::class);

        // echo drupal_render($form); exit(); <--- this was before

        return $form; //<--- this renders the whole page on callback from ajax, but the form tag is well
    }
}
```

with my `echo` statement only the form array is rendered, but not complete (form tag).

is there any method to render only my formfields, because the `return` will give me the whole page page (with wrapper header footer and sidebars).

thanks in advantage

Comment: You need to show us some of your code.

Comment: @Jaypan  i updated my broken code part.